# Convert meshgrid to vector for 2-value function

Tags: matlab, octave

I have a function like

```
f = @(x) x(1).^2 + x(2);
```

I want to draw its plot via `surf`, so I used `meshgrid` to generate input data:

```
[x, y] = meshgrid(-2:.2:2);
```

But if I try to pass it to the function like this

```
z = f([x; y])
```

I get just a single value in result.

Is there any way to do it except making a function that accepts two parameters (x, y) instead of a vector?

Comment: Surely you need to make your function accept two parameters? Why would you not want to?

Comment: Functions like `fminsearch`, `nonlin_min` want it in this form, so I would need to use anonymous function to convert vector to x, y.

Comment: Then you have two options, either use a wrapper function to convert it from the one form to the other (I'll add this to my answer) or vectorize your function `f` like I showed in the first example of my answer. It would make a lot more sense if you added your actual question using `fminsearch` than a question using `surf` btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you really do wany to make `f` take 2 parameters and I can't think of a good reason not to do it that way but this might be what you're after:

```
f = @(x) x(:,1).^2 + x(:,2)
```

Then you might need to call

```
z = f([x(:),y(:)])
```

After which you will probably need to call `reshape` on `z` so maybe `reshape(z,size(x))`

But I really think a 2 parameter function is a better way to go:

```
f2 = @(x1,x2)x1.^2 + x2
```

and now you can just go

```
z = f2(x,y)
```

Another way to go might be to use a wrapper function so if

```
f = @(x1,x2)x1.^2 + x2
```

but you really need a function that takes only one parameter then what about

```
f_wrapper = @(x) f(x{1},x{2}) %// using a cell array
```

or if you don't want to use a cell array then you could use a struct or a 3D array

```
f_wrapper = @(x) f(x.x1,x.x2) %// using structs
f_wrapper = @(x) f(x(:,:,1),x(:,:,2)) %// using a 3D matrix
```

Now you can use `f_wrapper` in something like `fmincon` after you package your `x` and `y` into a single variable so either a cell array, a struct or a 3D matrix. So for example if you are using the cell-array version above then try

```
inputVariable = {x,y}
```

So writing out the example in full

```
[x, y] = meshgrid(-2:.2:2);
f = @(x1,x2)x1.^2 + x2;
f_wrapper = @(x) f(x{1},x{2});
inputVar = {x,y};
z = f_wrapper(inputVar)
```

Comment: Why cell array and structs? Isn't just `fminsearch(@(x) f(x(1), x(2)))` enough?

Comment: Did you test it? `@(x) f(x(1), x(2)))` looks identical to your original if you asked me. It's only going to use the first two elements of `x` and thus it will completely ignore any elements beyond the second.

Comment: Yes, I am talking about wrapper for function with 2 parameters (`@(x, y) x.^2 + y`), the second part of you answer,

Comment: @AlexP11223 yes, so am I. Did you test it, I'm pretty sure that's not going to work. If you call `@(x) f(x(1), x(2)))` but you `x` had 4 elements, then `x(3)` and `x(4)` are never used. However, if you use one of the solutions I suggest, then all the elements will get used.

Comment: Yes, I tried it before. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_octave_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMdnNlOHZ3RDlobnc Not sure what do you mean about 4 elements, looks like you it would be the same for your solution, only 2 of them are used. Also `fminsearch(@(x) f(x{1}, x{2})` fails with error because `x` is not cell array.

Comment: @AlexP11223 yes well obviously you have to feed it a cell array in that case hence when I said 'package your `x` and `y` into a single variable', I'll add examples to my answer...

Comment: @AlexP11223 and if your application can't handle a cell array then just use the 3D matrix version

Answer (score 0):

```
clear
f = @(x) (x(:,:,1) - 1).^2 + 5 * (x(:,:,2) - 1).^2;
[x, y] = meshgrid(-2:.05:2); 
q(:,:,1)=x;
q(:,:,2)=y;
z = f(q);
surf(x,y,z)
```